# Print Multiplication table values into a text-box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the below script for printing multiplication table of 9 but it is not working as expected as the loop which I defined is not proper. Please help on this

- I want to take values from the table and to print it in a text box

```js
document.write("<table border='2' width='30%'>");
document.write("<tr><th>X</th><th>Y</th><th>X*Y</th></tr>");
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  document.write("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>" + "<td>9</td>" + "<td><input type='text' id='sum'></td></tr>");
  var x = i * 9;
  document.getElementById("sum").value = x;
}
document.write("</table>");
```

```html
<form>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, guys. This was the first question am asking on this platform and the results were awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the i value to the sum div like this:

```html
   <html><head>
 <form>
 <script language="JavaScript">
 document.write("<table border='2' width='30%'>");
 document.write("<tr><th>X</th><th>Y</th><th>X*Y</th></tr>");
 for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
 {
 document.write("<tr><td>"+i+"</td>"+"<td>9</td>"+"<td><input type='text' id='sum" + i +"'></td></tr>");
 var x=i*9;
 document.getElementById("sum" + i).value=x;
 }
 document.write("</table>");
</script>
</head><body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work .. happy coding :)

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let html = [];
 
  for(let i =1; i<=10 ; i++){
     html.push(`<tr> 
                  <td>9 * ${i}</td>
                  <td>= ${9 * i}</td>
                </tr>`)
  }
  $("#mulNine").append(html.join(""))
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id ="mulNine"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id Must be unique, you also use the same. Just paste X into a string with html

```
document.write("<table border='2' width='30%'>");
document.write("<tr><th>X</th><th>Y</th><th>X*Y</th></tr>");
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var x = i * 9;
  document.write("<tr><td>" + i + "</td>" + "<td>9</td>" + "<td><input type='text' value=\"" + x + "\"></td></tr>");

}
document.write("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly change your code and I got this:-

```js
document.write("<table border='2' width='30%'>");
        document.write("<tr><th>X</th><th>Y</th><th>X*Y</th></tr>");
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
        document.write("<tr><td>"+i+"</td>"+"<td>9</td>"+"<td><input type='text' id='sum' value=" + i*9+ "></td></tr>");
        
        }
        document.write("</table>");
```